# Checkbox 'change 'event works by binding event to parent div

Tags: jquery, checkbox, onchange

So far I've been thinking that jQuery's `change` event only worked on `<select>`, `<input type="checkbox">` and `<input type="radio">`.

But by accident, I have bound the `change` event to the parent of my checkbox, and it still works as if I had bound that event to the checkbox itself. How come this is working?

```
<div class="pwc">
    <input type="checkbox" id="pwc2" />
    <label for="pwc2">Only valid</label>
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).on('change', '#tabs .pwc', function(e) {
    ...
});
```

Instead of:

```
 $(document).on('change', '#tabs .pwc input:checkbox', function(e) {
    ...
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/change)(look at `Bubbles: Yes`) bubbles to the parent element.

In your case when the input element changes, a change event is triggered for the input element, then that gets propagated(bubbles) to the ancestor element till it reaches the root(document).

If you look at the [target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) of the `event` object within the handler you can find that the event was fired for the input element.

It is also the reason how you are able to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for the change event